# Can I put a receptacle in a closet?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, closet

I want to install a receptacle in a closet or two, but I've heard that receptacles are not allowed to be located in closets. I cannot find a concrete reference for that claim, though - it always seems to be an old wive's tale or an electrician-friend-of-a-friend. Is there such a restriction in the NEC, and if so, does it depend on the size of the closet?

[This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28196/can-i-install-junction-boxes-in-a-closet-and-if-so-what-kind-of-box) asks about junction boxes, which are similar, but could potentially be handled separately. A comment in that question indicates there is no restriction, but it would be good to have a definitive answer (especially as relevant for more recent versions of the NEC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  I have three instances in my house:  all were signed off by a competent electrical inspector.   (I am in the Portland, Oregon area.)

There is one in a bathroom closet, and one each in two medicine cabinets.  Handy for recharging a cordless vacuum, electric toothbrushes, and an electric shaver.

Comment: Indeed you can -- there is no prohibition in Art. 406 saying "no receptacles in closets"